# Return later ? PHP View file

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Lets say I have a view file that is built like this:

```
<html>
...
   <title><?= Functions::Text('title'); ?></title>
....
<body>

....
<?= Functions::Text('sometext'); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Functions::Text - would give me a db entry in table `texts` with `search_string` of title and sometext.

I want to pull out the data at once, and not per request (which mean - to collect an array of strings given to Texts (which is not that hard) - but I want the data, after the select query, to go to the exact places which requested the data.

which mean -

```
$query = select ... ;
... fetch ...
$results_of_fetch = array ('title'=>'Welcome!','sometext' => 'sometext!!');
```

And the view file -

```
<html>
...
   <title>Welcome!</title>
....
<body>

....
sometext!!

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is more related to Object rather than MVC.

So, i would like to make suggestion.

**Don't use  static method if you have to reuse object more that one time**.
By using non static method efficiently, you don't have to query database over and over again.

```
//create an object that takes parameter
//from a constructor or some other public method

class Function{

    public $title;
    public $text;
    public $footer;

    function _construct($id)
    {
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
    if (!$conn) {
        echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    if (!mysql_select_db("mydbname", $con)) {
        echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id=".$id." LIMIT 1";
    //if you are using id, then don't forget to add limit 1


    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if (!$result) {
        echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
        exit;
    }

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    //alternatively you can add loop check it at php manual
    $this->title = $row['title'];
    $this->text = $row['text'];
    $this->footer = $row['footer'];
    }
}
```

And in you layout(or view) file

```
//the first thing you need to do is instantiate an object
//don't use static method if you are reusing object again

<?php
    $function = new Function($id); 
            //pass some id or other parameter
     ?>

 <html>
...
   <title>
         <?= $function->title; ?>
        <!-- alternatively you can do with some method also -->
        </title> 
....
<body>

....
<?= $function->text; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

And I might not be understanding your necessity, you can comment, and please review your question.

Comment: It didnt answered my question, but it sure gave me a lead, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with AJAX and jQuery. jQuery, so that it'll be much easier.

```
jQuery

    $.post("fetchstuff.php", function(data){
       document.title = data.title;
       $("#txt1").html(data.sometext);
    });

fetchstuff.php
    <?php
        $sometext = "sometext";
        $title = "sometitle"
    ?>
```

Totally untested but output *should* look like this.

```
    <title>sometitle</title>
    ....
    <div id="txt1">sometext</div>
```

Comment: wont be realistic for site-wide usage.

Comment: If you want: Google not to index your site; to make everything work slow; to waste internet bandwidth and server resources, then... that's a great idea!